# How to open flutter view from an activity in kotlin?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, channel

I am working with flutter and the native part (kotlin), I used a channel to communicate, from kotlin I created a notification that is going to be updated in the background, what I want is that when I click on the notification, I open the application of flutter (the main page), does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, and it is by calling the package:

```
var packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
val intent1: Intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app")!!
contextLocal.startActivity(intent1)
```